# Broken images in table vaadin version 7.6.3

Tags: java, blob, vaadin, inputstream

When I scroll to the bottom of table and table loads it content, my images( images from **StreamResource** that are **Embedded**, I stored my images as blob in database) get broken.

First rows of table that contains *Embedded* images are shown just fine, but when I scroll down, the pictures that looks fine get broken.

*getAllPartners* method (here I load blob image from database):

```
public static Vector<PartnerDto> getAllPartner() {
        Vector<PartnerDto> result = null;

        PreparedStatement st = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            conn = Connect.getConnection();
            String sql = "select part_id,name, surname, picture from partner order by name, surname ";
            st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            System.out.println(sql);
            st.execute();
            rs = st.getResultSet();
            result = new Vector<PartnerDto>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                PartnerDto dto = new PartnerDto();
                dto.setPart_id(rs.getInt("part_id"));
                dto.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                dto.setSurname(rs.getString("surname"));
                Blob imageBlob = rs.getBlob("picture");
                if(imageBlob!=null){
                    InputStream binaryStream = imageBlob.getBinaryStream(1, imageBlob.length());                
                    dto.setPicture(binaryStream);
                }else{
                    dto.setPicture(null);
                }
                result.addElement(dto);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            result = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            Connect.closeConnection(rs, st, conn);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

My table (tPartners) initalization:

```
        tPartners.addContainerProperty("Slika uporabnika", Embedded.class, null);
        tPartners.addContainerProperty("Ime", String.class, null);
        tPartners.addContainerProperty("Priimek", String.class, null);
        tPartners.addContainerProperty("Rojstni datum", String.class, null);
        tPartners.addContainerProperty("Rojstni kraj", String.class, null);
        tPartners.addContainerProperty("Naslov", String.class, null);
        tPartners.addContainerProperty("Pošta", String.class, null);
        tPartners.addContainerProperty("Emšo", String.class, null);
        tPartners.addContainerProperty("Šola", String.class, null);
        tPartners.addContainerProperty("Razred", String.class, null);
        tPartners.addContainerProperty("Poklic", String.class, null);
        tPartners.addContainerProperty("Telefon", String.class, null);
        tPartners.addContainerProperty("Mail", String.class, null);
        tPartners.addContainerProperty("Klubska številka", String.class, null);
        tPartners.addContainerProperty("Številka kartice", String.class, null);
        tPartners.addContainerProperty("Datum včlanitve", String.class, null);
        tPartners.addContainerProperty("Opomba", String.class, null);
        tPartners.addContainerProperty("File type", String.class, null);

        tPartners.setSelectable(true);
        tPartners.setImmediate(true);
```

Code bellow shows how I *load images* in table:

```
             //get all partners
             Vector<PartnerDto> vResutl = DBLogika.searchPartner(text);

            for (int i = 0; i < vResutl.size(); i++) {
                //class that represent PartnerDto
                PartnerDto dto = vResutl.elementAt(i);

                String bd = "";
                String din = "";

                if (dto.getBorn_date() != null) {
                    bd = sdf.format(dto.getBorn_date());
                }

                if (dto.getDate_in() != null) {
                    din = sdf.format(dto.getDate_in());
                }

                Embedded emb=new Embedded();

                StreamResource.StreamSource source = new StreamResource.StreamSource() {

                    public InputStream getStream() {
                         //get inputstream from database, I save my image as longblob in database
                         return dto.getPicture();

                    }

                 };

               //uniq name for every file
               SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
               String filename = "mytablepic" + df.format(new Date()) + ".png";

               StreamResource sourceone=new StreamResource(source, filename);

               emb.setHeight("200px");
               emb.setWidth("150px");

               emb.setSource(dto.getPicture()==null? new ThemeResource("images/user_pic.jpg"): sourceone); 

                 tPartners.addItem((new Object[] {emb, dto.getName(), dto.getSurname(), bd, dto.getBorn_place(), dto.getAddress(),
                            dto.getPostDto().getPostName(), dto.getEmso(),
                            dto.getSchool(), dto.getPartClass(), dto.getJob(), dto.getPhone(),
                            dto.getMail(), dto.getClub_number(), dto.getCard_number(),
                            din, dto.getDesc(),dto.getFileextention()}), dto);

            }
```

What I am doing wrong?

Two images that shows my problem:

1. [how looks first time when I load content in table](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q19hsiq3fb2vto4/picturenormal.png?dl=0)
2. [broken image picture, when I scroll for example to the top, and then back to top](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y9gnoxbsgvc2jm7/picture.png?dl=0)

I am running my application on localhost on *Tomcat v8.0 Server.*

When I inspect images in Firefox with Firebug, it tells me: Could not load the image.

**Somehow when I scroll, and tables need to load it contant, images get broken...**

How could I solve this problem? Please help me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Answered by [*Max Schuster* in the Vaadin Forums](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/12584918/12585313):

I think you can't reuse the InputStream. Try storing the data as byte array in your DTO and return a fresh (ByteArray)InputSteam instance everytime StreamSource#getStream is called.

**But this approach will hit your ram pretty hard**, because you have to keep all images in the servers memory. Even if you don't need them.

I'd suggest that you create a custom StreamSource implementation that receives the image from the database every time StreamSource#getStream is called. Because you only need the image data if the clientbrowser asks for it. And this way the image data can be garbagecollected if it's not needed anymore.

Comment: please consider writing "a proper" answer (not just a link, that might vanish tomorrow)